# Use Zookeeper or Docker Swarm to implement a cluster?

Tags: microservices, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

I think one maintains the service objects of a microservice as a cluster, correct? To create a cluster, do I use Zookeeper or Docker Swarm ?

I already have a service-registry with Eureka.

Comment: docker swarm is a container orchestrator with service discovery and vxlan and other features.

zookeeper is a distributed kv store that is used for service discovery.

Comment: http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture/index.html **"Kafka uses ZooKeeper to manage the cluster. ZooKeeper is used to coordinate the brokers/cluster topology.** ZooKeeper is a consistent file system for configuration information. ZooKeeper gets used for leadership election for Broker Topic Partition Leaders." Can you please explain to me how Kafka and Zookeeper work together and why Zookeeper is in the Kafka Download-Package ?

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper is equivalent to the Docker Swarm Daemon in that it knows about the services and will act like a DNS for the services.

Zookeeper and Eureka are higher level constructs, and can work with any TCP/IP service.  Docker Swarm is superior in that it simply manages it for you using DNS.

You "can" use Zookeeper in a Docker Swarm, but I would avoid it unless it is really needed and keep it's scope small (namely because Kafka needs it).

Comment: Could you maybe name the functions / roles where Kafka needs it or and could be so friendly to list Zookeepers functions / roles compared to Eureka or Docker Swarm ? For example, Zookeeper is not just a `container orchestrator` but a `container manager` and Eureka does foremost fulfill the role of `service-discovery.` Can Docker Swarm also be used in the role as `service-discovery` ? And Zookeeper obviously also? But the latter two are different to Eureka in that they also do DNS? What is the function / role / purpose called then - to denote the difference to just `service discovery` ?

Comment: And also: Where do you know this from? I'm not sure if questions for book (and website) recommendations are covered by the code of conduct or not. I can't make it out in a trice. But is this real-world experience or do you have some good book/website/other-reads recommendations where the frameworks are explained together with their use-cases ? Thanks, von Spotz